# add a subview to an image without a fix position

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, rotation, subview

Hie every one, I have an image 'image' which is rotating with the accelerometer and I would like  to add a subview to it 'subimage' and that subimage rotate with image, So a sub view that is moving.I don't want to fix it's position like `subimage.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, image.view.frame.size.width, image.view.frame.size.height);` How can I do this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 1):

May be you mean :

```
 view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
 view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

?
It's will autoresize you image and it's subviews based on the device orientation.